# Trying to save an input text to an ArrayList and show the ArrayList on clickable ListView, app keeps crashing

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, input

So I'm trying to save an input (number) to an `ArrayList`, and then show the `ArrayList` on a clickable `ListView`.

When I'm trying to start the app it keeps crashing, Where did I go wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText numberIn;
    ListView numberList;
    Button saveBtn;
    String numberToSave;
    ArrayList<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        numberIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        numberList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        myNumbers();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allNumbers);

        numberList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        numberList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedNumber = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            }
        });

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                numberToSave = numberIn.getText().toString();
                myNumbers();
            }
        });
    }
    public void myNumbers(){
        allNumbers.add(numberToSave);
    }
}
```

Logcat:-

```
05-20 13:07:54.416 8449-8449/com.example.tsury.listex E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tsury.listex, PID: 8449
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:409)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2162)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: cat log error..?

Comment: what made you think you shouldn't include the error log in your code?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.tsury.listex, PID: 8449
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

//Is that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You try to call `.toString()` on a null object here:

`numberToSave = numberIn.getText().toString();`

You probably want to add a null check first:

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (numberIn.getText() != null {
            numberToSave = numberIn.getText().toString();
            myNumbers();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

If I want to represent the numbers with names? like I want the user to give a name to that number and the ListView will be displaying the names but when the user chooses the name I need to get the number, how can I do so?

Comment: @TsurYohananov Nevermind, my answer is wrong, I'll update it

Comment: Your answer worked for me, I just asked another thing. 

I changed the method like you said and it worked-

    public void myNumbers(){

        if (numberToSave != null){
            allNumbers.add(numberToSave);
        }

Comment: Can I show 2 Strings on my ListView and use just one of them? lets say I want the user to provide a number like we did already, and I also want him to provide a name for that number so on the lListView he'll see the name and the number

Comment: Yes but you may want to look up on 'custom listviews'. You can define your own layout and show as many thing as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the TextView before you inflate your layout, so it's a simple NullPointerExecption. Change your code:

public class ListViewDemo extends ListActivity {

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

TextView theFact;
String shareFact;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent)
    shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    listItems.add(shareFact);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}
If you press the button, it will call the addItems() function (as you set it), but it's not implemented yet, so it will generate an other error.

```
public void addItems(View v) {
    listItems.add(shareFact);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Add this function below your `onCreate()` method, and move the `listItems.add()` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` lines to this new method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(numberIn.getText() != null){
            numberToSave = numberIn.getText().toString();
            myNumbers();
        }
    }
});
```